# What is `--` called?

Tags: command, options

Recently I got to know of `--` that is double-hyphen which is used to tell a command that the option list has ended and what follows should not be considered as a option. So,

```
grep --  'search_word' *
```

would search for the given `search_word`. But you could see a unexpected behavior if you remove `--` and if there is a single file that start with `-`, which would switch on the option that match with the chars in *filename*.

What is this `--` called ? Is there any technical term to this ?

Comment: See the debate on [Why do unix-heads say “minus”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/why-do-unix-heads-say-minus) then double it.

Comment: @manatwork No, square it! Should we say “minus dash” or “dash minus”?

Comment: I just pronounce it "--".

Comment: I encounter regularity the `cd --` and `cd -` phenomena. while `cd --` means essentially just `cd` and thus change into your `$HOME`, `cd -` means put your self into previous directory. This becomes handy when you wanted to `cd ..` but as with german keyboard layout I mix it often up with `cd --`. `cd -` will then put you back. :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `--` is working for tools which use `getopt(3)` to process command line arguments and many API that parse POSIX style options.

From the manual page of `getopt(3)`:

> The interpretation of options in the argument list may be cancelled by the option `--' (double dash) which causes getopt() to signal the end of argument processing and return -1.

I would then say it is called *double dash*

Comment: But I'd bet there's some linguistic term for that.

Comment: getopt is not the only API that supports "--". Most APIs that parse POSIX style options in most languages support it. All POSIX utilities but `echo` and `[` support it

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks I edited the answer

Answer (score 5):

The only two names which I've head in practise are "double dash" for referring to it *aesthetically*, and "end of options" for referring to it *functionally*.

Comment: i've seen it refered to as 'last-option' as well.