# Is there a single '03 registered UNIX which can't do rm -- -foo at this point?

Tags: shell, rm

I'm trying to dispel this [uncertainty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus/1520#comment103384_1520) I have about the use of the *double-dash* (two hyphens, --) as an end of options delimiter(as opposed to a [long option prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126466)). It's possible some confusion arose when someone read that long options are a *GNU* convention and long options begin with `--`. But this is just unrelated to the *end of option [delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56372/44370)*.

The usage of Which is fully compliant with *[IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Utility Syntax Guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)*:

> The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following
>   arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the
>   '-' character.

So one can look at the `rm` manpages for [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html)(or [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)), [AIX](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/rm.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-17-57&lang=en), [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/rm-1.html#scrolltoc) and [HPUX](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02264845-2%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) - the well known UNIX '03 registered Unices:

- OSX, AIX and Solaris<sup>1</sup> refer to the `--` delimiter verbatim in *man rm*
- HPUX doesn't discuss it in *man rm* but has other commands which allow the said delimiter(such as [`touch`](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02273390-2%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken))

---

Is there a single *UNIX 03* [registered product](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/) which can't do `rm -- -foo` today? Is it Solaris... HPUX? Can they do it even though they don't document it? Can we generalize this to all commands on those platforms at this point?

---

<sup>1. The Solaris 11 manual says in a final note:  *If a - - and a - both appear on the same command line, the second is interpreted as a file.* And there is a space in between the first two hyphens. Is it just the hyphen or anything that would start with the hyphen in this context which would be interpreted as a file?</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Solaris 10:

```
~ touch testfile
~ rm -- testfile
~ ls testfile
testfile: No such file or directory
~ touch testfile
~ rm -- -f testfile
-f: No such file or directory
~ ls testfile
testfile: No such file or directory
~ rm - - -f testfile
-: No such file or directory
-f: No such file or directory
testfile: No such file or directory
~
```

So to answer your question, in Solaris 10, if the second instance starts with a hyphen, it is treated as a file.

Comment: Ok so in that case it accepts `-- -f testfile` with -f as one of two operands. But `- - -f testfile` reacts differently - even differently from the behavior described in the note on Solaris 11. Thanks!

Comment: No. In both cases whether the first argument is -- or - -, the -f is treated as a file name.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just meant that there is the extra `-: No such file or directory` i.e. 3 operands after a single dash.

Comment: Yes. That is correct :-)

Comment: Thank you, I will eventually have to validate this for myself on the target platforms but Solaris is, as always, a milestone!