# When and how was the double-dash (--) introduced as an end of options delimiter in Unix/Linux?

Tags: history, posix, gnu, arguments

I don't think the shell/utilities in [historical](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) Unix nor in something as "recent" as *4.4BSD* supported using a double-dash(or two consecutive hyphens) as an *end of options delimiter*. With *FreeBSD*, you can see for instance a note introduced in the `rm` [manpages](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) with the *2.2.1 release*(1997). But this is just the documentation for one command.

Looking at the oldest *GNU fileutils* [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/old/fileutils/ChangeLog-1997#n5191) I can find, I see this<sup>1</sup>(slightly altered):

```
Tue Aug 28 18:05:24 1990  David J. MacKenzie  (djm at albert.ai.mit.edu)

* touch.c (main): Don't interpret first non-option arg as a   <---
  time if `--' is given (POSIX-required kludge).  
* touch.c: Add long-named options.
* Many files: Include <getopt.h> instead of "getopt.h" since
  getopt.h will be in the GNU /usr/include.
* install.c: Declare some functions.
* touch.c, getdate.y, posixtime.y, mktime.c: New files, from bin-src.
* posixtime.y: Move year from before time to after it (but
  before the seconds), for 1003.2 draft 10.
```

This predates *Linux*. It's clearly to account for the fact that you might want to create a file with a name containing the same number of digits as a time [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/touch.html)(eight or ten-digit decimal number) - rather than specifying a timestamp for an existing file...

---

- So is it *posix.1* which introduced the double-dash (`--`) as an *end
  of options delimiter* in Unix shells?
- Did this all start because some people wanted to use digits in
  filenames with `touch` in the early '90s and then this went on in a piecemeal fashion one utility at a time for a decade??
- What is the spirited comment in the changelog about?
- When was *Guideline 10*(*The argument -- should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options.[...]*) introduced to the POSIX [Utility Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html)?

---

<sup>1. As opposed to [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/old/textutils/ChangeLog#n8074) i.e. documenting the [long options](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) in all commands usage globally, which is unrelated. On the other hand, you can see reference to the delimiter [appear](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/rm.c?id=acd9c429c01f8deceb7e6cb161023144a0d1e0f7) in something like *GNU* *rm.c* in 2000 as a comment, before being [exposed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/rm.c?id=6334db91d35e8984fc353f78f6b4a2af0553485a) to the end user in 2005(the *diagnose_leading_hyphen* function). But this is all much later and is about a very specific use case.</sup>

Comment: BSD4.3RENO at least had a `getopt` that supported `--`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You also made a [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56372/44370) about _getopt_ not being the only api able to deal with the delimiter. Does that mean that this had been provided for and worked before it was actually being used?? I'm afraid this is beyond me. Thank you!

Comment: It was probably used on an ad hoc basis by several random programs but I think it first became documented when `getopt` was written in the early 1980's. If someone can get the getopt paper from Uniforum '85, that might give some history.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, actually the getopt as found on SysIII (1980) supports `--`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the use of `--` as end-of-options-marker starts with `sh` and `getopt` in System III Unix (1980).

According to this [history of the Bourne Shell family](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne), the Bourne Shell *first* appeared in **Version 7 Unix** (1979). But it didn't have a way for `set` to [separate options from arguments](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/set-.html). So the original Bourne shell could do:

- `set -e` - turn on exit-on-error mode
- `set arg1 arg2 ...` - sets the positional parameters `$1=arg1`, `$2=arg2`, etc.

But: `set arg1 -e arg2` would give you `$1=arg1`, `$2=arg2`, and *turn on exit-on-error*. Whoops.

**System III Unix** (1980) fixed that bug and introduced `getopt`. According to `getopt`'s [man page](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=SysIII/usr/src/man/man1/getopt.1):

```
NAME
   getopt - parse command options

SYNOPSIS
   set -- `getopt optstring $∗`

DESCRIPTION
   Getopt is used to break up options in command lines for easy parsing by
   shell procedures, and to check  for  legal  options.   Optstring  is  a
   string  of  recognized  option letters (see getopt(3C)); if a letter is
   followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an  argument  which
   may or may not be separated from it by white space.  The special option
   -- is used to delimit the end of the options.  Getopt will place --  in
   the  arguments  at  the  end  of  the  options, or recognize it if used
   explicitly.  The shell arguments ($1 $2 . . .) are reset so  that  each
   option  is  preceded  by a - and in its own shell argument; each option
   argument is also in its own shell argument.
```

As far as I can tell, that's the *first* place it appears.

From there, it seems that other commands adopted the `--` convention to resolve argument parsing ambiguities (such as the examples with `touch` and `rm` you cite above) throughout the wild, standardless days of the 1980s.

Some of these piecemeal adoptions were codified in **POSIX.1** (1988), which is where the changelog comment about the "POSIX-required kludge" comes from.

But it wasn't until **POSIX.2** (1992) that the **Utility Syntax Guidelines** were adopted, which contain the famous Guideline 10:

```
Guideline 10:    The argument "--" should be accepted as a delimiter
                 indicating the end of options.  Any following
                 arguments should be treated as operands, even if they
                 begin with the '-' character.  The "--" argument
                 should not be used as an option or as an operand.
```

And that's where it goes from being a "kludge" to a universal recommendation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I had mostly ignored getopt in my "research" as I don't grasp why that sort of abstracted utility/function is required. Now I read this was reegineered [(getopts)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getopts.html) at some point to deal with blanks etc as sysv's `getopt` couldn't. I will read more about it! Thanks again!

Comment: If you don't grasp why a standard utility for parsing command-line options would be useful, maybe you haven't tried writing a shell parser for command-line options? It's kind of a pain! Sure would be nice if some other tool did this for me...

Also, keep in mind: in 1980 there was no Python, no Ruby, no Java, no Perl, no PHP - even C++ had yet to be invented, and the entire idea of "shell scripting" was still pretty new. So the idea of a standard command-line parser was still pretty novel!