# How do I specify command invocation for a mandatory short or long option?

Tags: command-line, man, options, documentation

I'm writing a specification for a tool that needs a `-f` / `--foo` option with a mandatory argument `BAR`, so for example these are valid calls:

```
tool -f BAR
tool --foo BAR
```

How do I specify this syntax in the invocation section of a manpage or another formal definition?

This would mean the options are not required, which is not what I intend:

```
tool [-f BAR | --foo BAR]
```

But simply omitting the brackets would not make sense either, since the pipe could be mistaken for an actual shell pipe.

POSIX [does not have long options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), and I cannot find a GNU reference for that either.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147745/44370) for context...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725675/is-there-a-standard-format-for-command-line-shell-help-text

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'd be common to interpret `tool -f BAR | --foo BAR` as «pipe the output of `tool -f BAR` into the command `--foo BAR`». So I'd use simply

```
tool -f BAR | --foo BAR
```

There's other possibilities in the wild using additional markup, specially if the invocation is more complex, to make it more obvious. Unlike with optional arguments and `[]` though, none of them are universally understood as *mandatory argument*, e.g.:

```
tool {-f BAR | --foo BAR}
```

or

```
tool <-f BAR | --foo BAR>
```

and even

```
tool (-f BAR | --foo BAR)
```

---

If you want to make sure that no one misreads the invocation specification, simply duplicate it:

```
tool -f BAR
tool --foo BAR
```

You'll see many manpages and help from programs use this multiple approach, although it's usually for different invocations instead of equivalent ones.