# Why is `sort < "$f1" ` preferred over `sort -- "$f1"`, and why is this preferred over `sort "$f1"`?

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection, arguments

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458074/674

> Remember to use `--` **when passing arbitrary arguments to commands** (or use redirections where possible). So `sort -- "$f1"` or better `sort < "$f1"` instead of `sort "$f1"`.

Why is it preferred to use `--` and redirection?

Why is `sort < "$f1"` preferred over `sort -- "$f1"`?

Why is  `sort -- "$f1"` preferred over `sort "$f1"`?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
sort "$f1"
```

fails for values of `$f1` that start with `-` or here for the case of `sort` some that start with `+` (can have severe consequences for a file called `-o/etc/passwd` for instance).

```
sort -- "$f1"
```

(where `--`  signals the end of options) addresses most of those issues but still fails for the file called `-` (which `sort` interprets as meaning its stdin instead).

```
sort < "$f1"
```

Doesn't have those issues.

Here, it's the shell that opens the file. It also means that if the file can't be opened, you'll also get a potentially more useful error message (for instance, most shells will indicate the line number in the script), and the error message will be consistent if you use redirections wherever possible to open files.

And in

```
sort < "$f1" > out
```

(contrary to `sort -- "$f1" > out`), if `"$f1"` can't be opened, `out` won't be created/truncated and `sort` not even run.

To clear some possible confusion (following comments below), that does not prevent the command from `mmap()`ing the file or `lseek()`ing inside it (not that `sort` does either) provided the file itself is seekable. The only difference is that the file is opened earlier and on file descriptor 0 by the shell as opposed to later by the command possibly on a different file descriptor. The command can still seek/mmap that fd 0 as it pleases. That is not to be confused with `cat file | cmd` where this time `cmd`'s stdin is a pipe that cannot be mmaped/seeked.

Comment: Just remember that using a redirection forces `sort` to read the data sequentially and you cannot `mmap` the file. While `sort` may not have much problems with it, consider the performance of `less <file` and `less file`. In first case `less` has to keep the whole contents of the file in the memory, in the second case it's allowed to read only those parts it wants. Now imagine that `file` is a 100GB log file...

Comment: @styrofoamfly: It's correct that `less <file` keeps all the file in memory, but it is not forced to, this is a shortcoming of less. Only `cat file | less` is forced to. Check out `less /dev/fd/0 <f`, which doesn't keep the file in memory, even though it receives it on stdin. It's a common misconception that stdin in Unix is unseekable. It fact, it can be seekable, depending on the file type.

Comment: @styrofoamfly  Do you mean that `read()` read data sequentially from a file, while `mmap()` read the entire file into memory at once?

Comment: @Tim, `read()` reads (at the current offset, the amount specified), `mmap()` maps the file in memory, so that dereferencing the corresponding memory addresses may cause the data to be read from the file (if it  hasn't been read already or has been evicted since it was already read, using a page fault mechanism).

Comment: One should always remember that `--` serving to mark the end of the option list is a GNU *convention*, not a guaranteed behavior.  It is up to individual programs to honor it, and not all do.  That's another reason to prefer redirection where that option is available.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No. That dates back to at least as far back as getopt from SysIII in 1980 before the GNU project was started and is required to be supported for most standard utilities including `sort` by POSIX. But it's true that it's not always supported.

Comment: My apologies, @StéphaneChazelas, you are right about the origin of the convention, and I will furthermore stipulate that the POSIX specification for the `getopt()` C function recognizes this significance of the argument `--`.  But the main point is the one that you accept: argument handling is the domain of individual programs, and not all treat `--` specially.

Answer (score 18):

The issue is file names beginning with a dash. `sort "$f1"` doesn't work if the value of `f1` starts with `-` because the command will interpret the value as an option. This usually results in an error but it could even [cause a security hole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). With `sort -- "$f1"`, [the double dash argument `--` mean “no options beyond this point”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter) so the value of `f1` will not be interpreted as an option. But there is still one edge case: if the value of `f1` is a dash and nothing else, then it isn't an option, it's the argument `-`, which means “standard input” (because the argument is an input file; for an output file it would mean “standard output”).

Using redirection avoids all of these pitfalls.

This applies to most commands, not just `sort`.

Comment: Are you saying that `sort < "$f1"` would work if the value was equal to `-`? It doesn't in any shell I've tried.

Comment: @grawity, compare `seq 10 > -; sort -` with `seq 10 > -; sort < -`.