# Grep over multiple files redirecting to a different filename each time

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection, filenames

I have a directory full of .tsv files and I want to run a grep command on each of them to pull out a certain group of text lines and then save it to an associated text file with a similar file name. So for example, if I was grepping just one of the files, my grep command looks like this:

```
grep -h 8-K 2008-QTR1.tsv > 2008Q1.txt
```

But I have a list of tsv files that look like:

```
2008-QTR1.tsv
2008-QTR2.tsv
2008-QTR3.tsv
2008-QTR4.tsv
2009-QTR1.tsv
2009-QTR2.tsv
2009-QTR3.tsv
...
```

And after grepping they need to be stored as:

```
2008Q1.txt
2008Q2.txt
2008Q3.txt
2008Q4.txt
2009Q1.txt
2009Q2.txt
2009Q3.txt
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The grep pattern is always the same?

Comment: Yes, the grep pattern is always that same, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

In ksh93/bash/zsh, with a simple `for` loop and parameter expansion:

```
for f in *-QTR*.tsv
do 
  grep 8-K < "$f" > "${f:0:4}"Q"${f:8:1}".txt
done
```

This runs the `grep` on one file at a time (where that list of files is generated from a wildcard pattern that requires "-QTR" to exist in the filename as well as a ".tsv" ending to the filename), redirecting the output to a carefully-constructed filename based on:

- the first four characters of the filename -- the year
- the letter `Q`
- the 9th character of the filename -- the quarter

Comment: `<"$f"` is unnecessary here and could be just `"$f"`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Stéphane edited that in, but it's useful if you want consistent error messages (from your shell, versus from the various utilities); see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458268/117549

Comment: Fascinating, thanks.

Comment: This worked, thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

The obligatory POSIX `sh` variant:

```
#! /bin/sh -
ret=0
for file in [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]-QTR[1234].tsv; do
  base=${file%.tsv}
  grep 8-K < "$file" > "${base%%-*}Q${base##*-QTR}".txt || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret"
```

Comment: Why `<"$f"`? Redirection not necessary there.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, using redirections has many advantages over passing the file as argument. Note that it's also generally less work, so I'd say it's more the _passing the file as argument_ that is not necessary here (as in this case, we don't need `grep` to know the name of the file, just its contents). See [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```
for f in  200{8..9}-QTR{1..4}.tsv; do
    grep "pattern" $f > $(sed "s/[-RTtsv]*//g" <<< $f)txt;
done
```

Walkthrough: Set up an expansion that creates a list of your filenames

```
200{8..9}-QTR{1..4}.tsv
```

expands to

```
2008-QTR1.tsv 2008-QTR2.tsv 2008-QTR3.tsv 2008-QTR4.tsv 2009-QTR1.tsv 2009-QTR2.tsv 2009-QTR3.tsv 2009-QTR4.tsv
```

and to do every year and quarter to date would be

```
20{08..19}-QTR{1..4}.tsv
```

Iterate over the list `for..do..done`, extract the pattern you are looking for from the file

```
grep "pattern" $f
```

and redirect to  the new filename formed by deleting the unwanted characters with `sed` and adding the `txt` suffix

```
$(sed "s/[-RTtsv]*//g" <<< $f)txt
```

or

```
$(sed "s/[-RT]*//g" <<< ${f%%.*}.txt)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this brace-expansion idea hard-codes the expected filenames; it would not pick up newer or older files, and would complain of missing files in the range. Not a deficiency, except the OP showed a file name listing ending in "..."

Comment: Very true, but so does @stephanechazelas to an extent. What this doesn't do is assume that every tsv file is required, nor that the substrings extracted will conform to OP's pattern. `Bananannanan-QTRanana.tsv` wont, that's for sure. What it does do is allow OP to process a selected subset of known files, Swings and roundabouts.

Comment: Indeed, the three of us so far came up with different approaches; I just enjoy adding a little explanation about how it works so that the OP (or future readers) understand *why* it works so that they know if they can adapt it to their situation.

Comment: Anyone for golf?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid an explicit loop, there is the following solution. Someone will maybe be able to improve it.  It looks something like this.

```
ls -1 *.tsv | xargs -n1 -I'{}' bash -c 'f="{}";grep 8-K $f > ${f//[^0-9Q]/}.txt'
```

1. *ls* just lists the files you want to process
2. *xargs* process each of these files, on by one (*-n1*)
3. a *bash* shell is launched to be able to process the strings (cf point 5)
4. Sets the filename to variable *$f*
5. *${f//[^0-9Q]/}* removes all the characters you don't want in the .txt filenames (so this is specific to your example)

Pros:
 - Simple one liner

Cons:
 - A bash process is started for each file processed

Maybe is there a similar solution without using bash, but I don't know one (for example, eval shouldn't work in this context)

Comment: Alternative with awk: grep -H 8-K *.tsv | awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' '{fn=gensub(/[^0-9Q]/,"","g",$1) ".txt";for(i=1;i<NF;i++){$i=$(i+1)};NF--;print $0 > fn}', but we start here to another world that bash, with awk.

Comment: Pure awk, something like: awk '/8-K/{print > (gensub(/[^0-9Q]/,"","g",FILENAME) ".txt")}' *.tsv