# Please help with sed command to grab specific text

Tags: linux, sed

I have a txt file which is an output from an api call to JIRA which creates a task.

In this file, I have this text (issue # can change):

```
"key":"JIRA-90"
```

I'd need to grab the JIRA-90 but can't seem to figure out how to do it with sed.

JIRA-90 can of course change as that is the issuetype in JIRA.

Comment: You are, I suspect, getting a JSON blob back from the Jira API.  Kick the JSON output into `jq`, which is designed to parse JSON (which, being an irregular language, is something that `sed` is not).

Comment: Unfortunately, we are locked down and I can't install jq.. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*"key":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' < your-file
```

Using the usual idiom: `sed -n 's/pattern/replacement/p` which does a `s`ubstitution and only `p`rints the resulting pattern space if it's successful (`n`ot printing the pattern space at the end of each cycle as it would do without `-n`).

Comment: This is close. However, I'm getting all the text after the JIRA-90 value.  i.e. output shows:   JIRA-90","self":"https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/2345555"}[user@server

Comment: Then the `.` in the `\(.*\)` needs to be changed to only match expected text. Here's one way of doing that: change `\(.*\)` to `\(\w\+-\w\+\)`

Comment: Funny enough, this produces the exact same output.

Comment: @SethEfrat, there's no such `,"self":...` in the sample in your question. Please clarify what exactly you want to extract from exactly what shape of data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why indirect the file with `<`?  `sed` takes a file to parse as a parameter.

Comment: @DopeGhoti https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458268/117549

Comment: Hi @StéphaneChazelas, the file that curl outputs to has quite a bit of header info and at the bottom is this line:  {"id":"1234567","key":"JIRA-90","self":"https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/1234567  So, I'm just trying to get the text after "key" and before ,"self"  Again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you Stéphane for contributing your time and effort on this. While it didn't directly solve my issue, it did help me get a better understanding of sed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file contains more than 1 name-value pair, consider this:

```
$ awk -F'":"' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"|"[[:space:]]*$/,""); f[$1]=$2} END{print f["key"]}' file
JIRA-90
```

That approach lets you populate an array (`f[]` above) with the name to value mappings and then you can just print the values by their names whenever you like.

```
$ cat file
        "foo":"127"
        "key":"JIRA-90"
        "bar":"hello world"

$ awk -F'":"' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"|"[[:space:]]*$/,""); f[$1]=$2} END{print f["bar"], f["key"]}' file
hello world JIRA-90

$ awk -F'":"' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"|"[[:space:]]*$/,""); f[$1]=$2} END{print f["foo"] * 3}' file
381

$ awk -F'":"' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"|"[[:space:]]*$/,""); f[$1]=$2} END{for (i in f) print i "=" f[i]}' file
key=JIRA-90
foo=127
bar=hello world
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using your solution but, I get an empty line returned so it doesn't seem to pick up what is after "key"

Comment: Then your posted sample input doesn't adequately reflect your real input. When posting sample input/output it's important to show the text you want to find **in context** among the text you want to find it in.

Comment: Thank you Ed for providing these examples. I appreciate the time you put into this and I'll be sure to pay it forward in the future :)